# How resolve error "TF84021 - Could not create the work item list" with TFS Office Integration?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I opened an excel file generated with TFS Office Integration (TFS 2017 update 1 on premises). I obtained this error "TF84021 - Could not create the work item list". How resolve this error? What caused this error?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: No, we didn't resolve the issue yet. Could the problem be caused by the use of Office 365 to generate the excel file, then opening the file with another version (Office 2016) of Excel? Furthermore I was confused by the fact that in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=open-excel#prerequisites Office 365 seems to be supported, in this other link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops#microsoft-office-integration Office 365 appears to be unsupported.

Comment: I am afraid that is the reason for this issue. As the state in your first link: **To connect Excel to Azure Boards, you must have installed Office Excel 2010 or later version, including Office Excel 365.** So, it need to use excel to generate the excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How resolve error “TF84021 - Could not create the work item list” with TFS Office Integration?

To use that extension, you need make sure you have installed the requires Microsoft Excel and one of the following clients to be installed:

- [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#visual-studio-enterprise-2017) or later
- [Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2017) or later

I have installed that extension and tested the "open work item query result in microsoft excel" through the excel extension with below process:

- Click the “Open in Excel” in Query Results after I installed the
  Excel extension for my organization:

  [image]
- Click the “Open TfsProtocolHandler.exe” button in popup dialog

  [image]

Now we can see it in Excel opened automatically:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have it set up. It was me even who created the sheet in the first place, so I'm all set up. But I changed my password and I'm guessing that should probably be the issue. Too bad that even logging off and back on on Office isn't fixing this. Lets see if it just takes some time to fix itself

Comment: Issue solved. I just had to wipe my credentials manager clean, log out of Office and log out of DevOps and OneDrive for good measure, restart the PC and log back in on everything

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you're not authenticated to the TFS server. I installed the prerequisites, created the Excel file, etc. Put it away for a couple of months (during which I had changed my Windows password). Tried to open the Excel file and got this error. I opened Visual Studio and hit a Git repo on the server and was prompted for my password (VS 2022). Once that got resolved, the Excel file opened successfully.

Comment: That does makes sense. I've just changed my password and it started returning that error. Reconnecting to Azure DevOps didn't solve the issue, though. I'll wait for a few days to see if it fixes itself over time. I assume this may just be taking some time to spread to all services (or else I wouldn't have been able to create the spreadsheet in the first place)

Comment: Issue solved. I just had to wipe my credentials manager clean, log out of Office and log out of DevOps and OneDrive for good measure, restart the PC and log back in on everything