# Getting error when trying to create spreadsheets from a TFS query

Tags: excel, tfs

I have used the TFS to Excel functionality for several years. Last Friday it suddenly stopped working.  I get the error `TF84021 Can't create the work item list.`  If I try again it will spin and then bring up the same error. This usually happens 2 or 3 times then Excel will open as a read-only which removes the link to TFS.  I have tried to configure the server connection and get error `TF400324. Services not available from server. The underlying connection was closed.`
This is impacting a small group of people with the same job function (Scrum Masters and BAs). Management and developers can use it just fine.
My help desk remoted into my machine and tried it with his creds and it didn't work. We ran it through Fiddler and the log showed an error but it didn't have any information.
I am using TFS2017 Version 15.117.27414.0 which I believe is update 3, Visual Studio 2017 and Excel 2016. As well as ADO in the cloud (not on prem).
I have gone into Excel to verify the com add-in is present and checked.  I have reinstalled the add-in just in case it was corrupted.  I have tried to remove my TFS server and re-add although I knew that couldn't be the problem as it occurs on ADO as well.
I'm at a loss. Any thoughts as to what to try next?

Comment: Since ADO has the same problem, it seems that this problem is related to Excel. Have you tried reinstalling Excel? You mentioned that this affects a small group of people. They also cannot connect to ADO? Do you have the same issue if you use the "open in excel" option in queries? Please share a screenshot of your error messages.

Comment: Hope you are doing well. Would you please share your latest information about this issue?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I do get the errors when using the Open in Excel option.  Here are screenshots.  I hope it helps.  I'm not able to share a screenshot but I get error TF84021 Could not create work item list.  That happens a couple of times then opens the spreadsheet read only with the link to TFS gone.  I tried to reconnect to the server and get error TF400324 Services not available from server.  That's as far as I can get.  The ADO error I get is TF80066.

Comment: Have you installed the office integration tools? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2017

Comment: You can refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62450051/how-resolve-error-tf84021-could-not-create-the-work-item-list-with-tfs-offic) about TF84021 Could not create work item list.  TF80066 means you don't have enough permissions. You can try to test whether there are the same problems in your own organization.

Comment: @spikey_richie actually that's the fist thing i looked at to make sure it was still there.  I have since deleted it and added it again just to make sure it wasn't corrupt.

Comment: Thanks @WalterQian-MSFT.  I saw that before.  I don't think this is the issue since it still works for some people in my organization but not me and a few others.  We are working with Microsoft to see if they can help diagnose the problem.  I'll post if/when we figure it out.